# Git incorrectly detects changes when in fact additive

Tags: git, git-merge, merge-conflict-resolution, git-merge-conflict

I have this merge conflict:

```
<<<<<<< HEAD
async def func1():
    stuff (func1)
=======
async def func2():
    different stuff (func2)
>>>>>>> origin/master

    stuff in common between func1 and func2
<<<<<<< HEAD
    more stuff (func1)
=======
    different more stuff(func2)
>>>>>>> origin/master
    differrent stuff in common between func1 and func2
<<<<<<< HEAD
    final stuff (func1)
=======
    different final stuff(func2)
```

I want both func1 and func2 to exist at the end. Git thinks the one commit has modified the other when in fact it is additive. If it helps, func1 and func2 were created by copy pasting code from func0 and things like "more stuff" could resemble several lines of code.

The desired final result would look like

```
async def func1():
    stuff (func1)

    stuff in common between func1 and func2
    more stuff (func1)

    differrent stuff in common between func1 and func2
    final stuff (func1)

async def func2():
    different stuff (func2)

    stuff in common between func1 and func2
    different more stuff(func2)
    
    differrent stuff in common between func1 and func2
    different final stuff(func2)
```

(ignore any minor whitespaces issues, this is a contrived example)

If were to guess I want to take all of "theirs" then add "ours" or the other way around.

Thanks!

Comment: Are these changes located on the same lines in the same file in their respective branches? Did the HEAD's branch have `func2` when the branch was created? If not, it's not additive, and git will be confused if another function (i.e. `func1`) is in the same location.

Comment: You need to look at the *merge base* version. Set `merge.conflictStyle` to `diff3` and re-create the conflict.

Comment: Oh fascinating. Really cool insight. So further context. There was branch_func1 that got merged to master, and now there is branch_func2 that is getting the conflicts while going into master. Within branch_func1 `func1` is indeed defined on the same line number as `func2` within branch_func2. Interesting coincidence!  I just tried moving func down 1 line, I'm guessing git ignores the whitespace. I could move func2 to a different place in the file, but, that is not satisfying! haha

Answer (score 1):

You know what you intended, so it's easy for you to see what the result should be, and not easy to see all the other things that might be intended in other, indistinguishable cases. This is why Git punts when anything looks less than clearly independent. You're looking at guesses Git correctly identified as unsafe.

When Git declines to automerge for you it shows you why it's done so, but there's no guarantee it correctly identified the boundary of the intended change. That's what's happened here: your two changes look similar enough that they look like two variations on a number of disjoint change.

Add and commit the correct result, and you're done.

A lot of people have been very interested for a very long time in ways to make Git reliably identify and resolve more conflicts. There is a *lot* of history available to test any improvements you can imagine against; it's great to find rules that correctly identify your case and produce the result you want, not so great if they silently produce bad results in other cases.

Comment: That is fair, the two are definitely very similar. "stuff" and "different stuff" are the same variables with different values for example. I suppose what I'm actually looking for is a way to use git to take the func2 changes and just past them above/below func1. I can of course do this manually, I was just hoping git could do it for me. Like cherry picking func2 or something. Maybe even make a diff/patch, then apply it to a different line somehow.

Comment: @sifh98h28fh29hews something like a git mergetool could help.
There are plenty of software that help to achieve the result easier than just editing a file full of conflicts. I'd recommend to try Meld for a start. It's cross-platform and works really well.

Comment: Any decent programmer's editor will have a Git plugin offering index access, you can just c&p the hunks straight out of the ours/theirs buffers, and using vimdiff as a merge tool it's built in.